# loop through list of elements and update hidden field separated by vertical line and comma

Tags: jquery

I can have a unlimited set of list items and form fields (limited) in li:

```
    <li id="apr1">
    <textarea class="thisistext">blablabla</textarea>
    <input class="imgid" type="hidden" value="450">
    <input class="order" type="hidden" value="1">
    </li>
    <li id="apr2">
    <textarea class="thisistext">bimbimbim</textarea>
    <input class="imgid" type="hidden" value="455">
    <input class="order" type="hidden" value="2">
    </li>

etc
```

What I want is, write the contents of of all field in hidden field for update to database:
The format should be values from field seperated by comma and groups seperated by vertical line |

"imgid,order,thisistext|imgid,order,thisistext|etc...  "

```
<input id="thedatafield" value="450,1,blablabla|455,2,bimbimbim| etc...">
```

How would you accomplish this?  Probalby, the .serialize() would help, but the important part is textarea, which can be in pure html format.

Comment: can you please post your jquery code also? doesn't serialize work for you?

Comment: Serialize by itself does not add group seperator. Just seperates all values with comma. The example below seem fine for me. I'll try to implement and see if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

**JQUERY:**

```
var sAllValue = '';
$("li").each(function(){

    var vImgValue = $(this).find(".imgid").val();
    if(sAllValue == "")
        sAllValue = vImgValue+",";
    else
        sAllValue = sAllValue+vImgValue+",";    
    var vOrderValue = $(this).find(".order").val();
    sAllValue = sAllValue+vOrderValue+",";
    var vTextArea = $(this).find("textarea").val();
    sAllValue = sAllValue+vTextArea;

    sAllValue = sAllValue+"|";

});
$("#hdnAllVAlue").val(sAllValue);
alert("All values: "+$("#hdnAllVAlue").val());
```

**ASPX:**

```
<li id="apr1">
    <textarea class="thisistext">blablabla</textarea>
    <input class="imgid" type="hidden" value="450">
    <input class="order" type="hidden" value="1">
    </li>
<li id="apr2">
    <textarea class="thisistext">bimbimbim</textarea>
    <input class="imgid" type="hidden" value="455">
    <input class="order" type="hidden" value="2">
</li>
<br />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAllVAlue" runat="server" />
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oqahi4)**

Comment: Sukhi - you are my hero now!  This is working as expected. Thank you! Stackowerflow - long lice to you!

Comment: @jam: glad it worked for u and don't forget to accept the answer which sort out yr problem.Happy coding...